# Firefox:Problem with Status in OnStateChange in Proxy environment

Tags: macos, firefox-addon, xpcom

I am trying to use the status to see if there is an error in C++ XPCOM component in my observer class on Mac.

```
OnStateChange(
   nsIWebProgress *aWebProgress,
   nsIRequest *aRequest,
   PRUint32 aStateFlags,
   nsresult aStatus)
{

}
```

In proxy environment the `aStatus` parameter is always true though the browser fails to load the page.

In non-proxy environments it gives the proper value (error) in status.

You can see it if you try accessing http://10.1.3.3/ (some random IP). With a proxy the status is zero (success) and without a proxy you get an error value.

Should some parameters be set to get the proper error value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior if you use an HTTP proxy. A non-zero `aStatus` means "didn't get any response because of some error". On the other hand, a zero `aStatus` value means "there was some response, check `nsIHttpChannel.responseStatus` to see whether the request was successful". That's what you get if the server responds with "404 Not Found" for example - `aStatus` will be zero (you got a response back) but `nsIHttpChannel.responseStatus` will be 404.

It's the same with an HTTP proxy because the proxy will always send a response back, probably "502 Bad Gateway" if it couldn't connect to the server. That's what the browser gets so `aStatus` will be zero and `nsIHttpChannel.responseStatus` will be 502. So in you code you should do something like this:

```
OnStateChange(
   nsIWebProgress *aWebProgress,
   nsIRequest *aRequest,
   PRUint32 aStateFlags,
   nsresult aStatus)
{
  if (FAILED(aStatus))
  {
    // Got no response
  }
  else
  {
    nsCOMPtr<nsIHttpChannel> channel = do_QueryInterface(aRequest);
    PRUint32 status = 0;
    if (channel)
      channel->GetResponseStatus(&status);
    if (status >= 400)
    {
      // Got an HTTP error
    }
    else
    {
      // Success!
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that it is expected behavior